# Sbt hook for custom µtest test runner

Tags: scala, testing, sbt, scala.js, utest

I'm using [µtest](https://github.com/lihaoyi/utest) in a Scala sbt project. I want to run various test classes with a custom made test runner, which consists of code like this

```
val results = AnotherClassWithTests.myTests.run()
println(results.leaves.count(_.value.isSuccess))
```

I want it to be executed when running sbt test, and the only way I've found is to [extend utest.Testsuite](https://github.com/lihaoyi/utest#running-tests-with-sbt) and leave the tests method empty.

This way, sbt will find the class and run it, but the solution doesn't seem ideal. I can prevent sbt's runner to execute `AnotherClassWithTests` by not having it extend utest.Testsuite, but still I'd get unneccessary output from the µtests default test runner along with my own ouput.

How can I hook my runner to `sbt test` without that hack and run all my tests with it, skipping µtests default runner?

Can I access the list of µ-tests that are detected by sbt, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can completely override the behavior of the `test` task, with one that simply executes your main class. Taking inspiration from https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/blob/v0.6.5/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/scala/scalajs/sbtplugin/ScalaJSPluginInternal.scala#L547-L549

```
/** Run a class in a given environment using a given launcher */
def jsRun(env: JSEnv, cp: CompleteClasspath, mainCl: String,
    launcher: VirtualJSFile, jsConsole: JSConsole, log: Logger) = {

  log.info("Running " + mainCl)
  log.debug(s"with JSEnv of type ${env.getClass()}")
  log.debug(s"with classpath of type ${cp.getClass}")

  // Actually run code
  env.jsRunner(cp, launcher, log, jsConsole).run()
}

def launcherContent(mainCl: String) = {
  val parts = mainCl.split('.').map(s => s"""["${escapeJS(s)}"]""").mkString
  s"${CoreJSLibs.jsGlobalExpr}$parts().main();\n"
}

def memLauncher(mainCl: String) = {
  new MemVirtualJSFile("Generated launcher file")
    .withContent(launcherContent(mainCl))
}

test in Test := {
  val mainClass = "path.to.AnotherClassWithTests"
  jsRun((jsEnv in Test).value, (scalaJSExecClasspath in Test).value, mainClass,
      memLauncher(mainClass), (scalaJSConsole in Test).value, streams.value.log)
}
```

To obtain the list of tests that have been detected, you can use the sbt task `(definedTests in Test).value`, or possibly `(definedTestNames in Test).value`.